# Join latest record based on calendar ID

Tags: sql-server, calendar

I have two tables, one with values of exchange rates, and one with transactions. Since there are weekends, where the exchange rates doesn't exist, I need to get the latest exchange rate available. Can anyone help me? I have the two following sample tables with the desired outcome:

```
DateID   | Exchange rate
20200514 | 5,2
20200515 | 5,4
20200518 | 5,3
20200519 | 5,2

DateID   | Transaction | Desired Exchange rate
20200514 | 500         | 5,2
20200514 | 400         | 5,2
20200517 | 300         | 5,4
20200518 | 500         | 5,3
```

The code I used is the following:

```
SELECT 

t.DateID, 
t.Transaction,
MAX(e.Exchange Rate)

FROM dbo.TransactionTable t
LEFT JOIN dbo.ExchangeRate e ON e.DateID <= t.DateID
```

This tends to work with very little data, but it seems there is too much. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUB QUERY` to attain this:

```
declare @T table(
DateID   INT ,[ Exchange rate] VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @T values(20200514,'5,2')
Insert into @T values(20200515,'5,4')
Insert into @T values(20200518,'5,3')
Insert into @T values(20200519,'5,2')

declare @R  table(
DateID   INT ,[ Transaction] INT)
Insert into @R values(20200514, 500)
Insert into @R values(20200514, 400)
Insert into @R values(20200517, 300)
Insert into @R values(20200518, 500)
```

Main Query:

```
SELECT M.DATEID,M.[ TRANSACTION],S.DES_EXCHANGE_RATE FROM @R M
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DATEID, MAX([ EXCHANGE RATE]) AS DES_EXCHANGE_RATE
FROM @T
GROUP BY  DATEID) S ON S.DATEID=M.DATEID
```